# What can cause direction to wobble?

Tags: handlebars, steel, touring-bikes

When I cycle I can feel wobbling in the direction. I feel it even more and can even see it if I ride no handed. It gets really bad when I put luggage on my low rider.

The bike is a 62cm touring steel bike with 700 wheels, the head tube is really long, about 9 inches without the crowns. The wheel oscillate by about 2 degrees with luggage on at about 35 km/h (22 mph). The handle bar being kept about straight. So all the wobbling is torsion in the steering tube.

Comment: Your rack is on the front?

Comment: I got a rack on the back and a low rider in front.

Comment: "Wobbling in the direction" What?

Answer (score 1):

I found it is called speed wobble. It can come from loose headset, loose spokes, bad tire, misaligned wheel, too-high saddle (http://www.roadbikerider.com/advanced-skills/speed-wobble), geometry and  physiology might be the problem (http://cyclingtips.com.au/2011/03/speed-wobble-when-the-bike-shakes-its-head/).

One way to avoid it is to hold the top tube in descent.